# Copying files on hard drive use double space

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, file-transfer

Under Windows 10, when copying/downloading/moving files on/from/to my second hard drive (a WD750GB wdc wd7500bpkx-80hpjt0), the disk space is changing by twice the size of the file.

So for example, if I have 10GB available on my hard drive (D:) and I copy a 2GB file to it (from C: to D: for example), I will have 6GB left. C: and D: are in NTFS.

How to find the source of this situation and correct it ?!

Comment: I think I do have the same problem. Did you make any progress?

Answer (score 2):

When using compression, windows seems to have problems calculating free space.

I was also effected by the same problem as you, and was solved by disabling compression.

Actually I don't have any sources as this is my own experience.

Comment: Can you give a step-by-step explanation for "disabling compression"? Did disabling compression end up using more actual disk space just for the sake of *reporting* accurate disk space usage?

Answer (score 0):

One of the drives can be mapped in some folder on other drive. That is possible by mapping the drive in explorer or using `subst` command.

Comment: so 1- how to find out if there is a mapping (I typed subst but nothing is displayed in cmd) and 2- even if I copy a file from D:\a.mp3 to D:\b.mp3, I have same situation and space available will decrease by twice the size of a.mp3 (or b.mp3 since it's the same).

Comment: 1 - you can find all mappings by the command you used and in explorer. 2 - I don't know why that happens, I've given you the nearest answer, but it is not it, I think.